# How to export a PrimeNG datatable into PDF or Excel?

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-datatables

I have created my Datatable using the UI library PrimeNG. Now I want to export the data to PDF, Excel using Angular 4 framework.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Check the documentation: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/export There is a function to export datatable to .csv. Although, there's is no ready-to-use solution for .pdf files.

Answer (score 1):

There is just only one option for exporting and it is csv. You can follow the Pdf feature [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/534).